# In Matlab for a matrix(m,n) equivalent matrix(:) , colon, in python

Tags: python, matlab

I need to find the equivalent from matlab of A(:) in python. Where A is a matrix(m,n):

For example:

```
A =

 5     6     7
 8     9    10
```

> > A(:)

ans =

```
 5
 8
 6
 9
 7
10
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/2586922) what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the column-major result (to match the Matlab convention), you probably want to use the transpose of your `numpy` matrix, and then the `ndarray.ravel()` method:

```
m = numpy.array([[ 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9, 10 ]])
m.T.ravel()
```

which gives:

```
array([ 5,  8,  6,  9,  7, 10])
```

Comment: I am sorry and which one would be the reverse operation? i.e. converting the result of m.T.ravel() into the m matrix?

Comment: To reverse the operation, you could try `m.reshape((2,3), order='F')`, which uses the Fortran (column-major) ordering to repack the sequence of elements into a 2x3 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by reshaping your array with `numpy.reshape`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

```
import numpy
m = numpy.array([[ 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9, 10 ]])
print(numpy.reshape(m, -1, 'F'))
```

Comment: You can use reshape to do that aswell!

aMatrix = numpy.reshape(aVector,2,3)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19496178)

Comment: Okay, understood.